# Laptop freezes, keyboard LEDs flashing

Tags: 14.04, freeze, crash

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit). Recently my laptop freezes unexpectedly and keyboard lights start to blink. It's not possible to switch to tty (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> doesn't work), so it's completely unresponsive.

I haven't made any hardware or software changes recently. Also there is no discernible pattern as to when this happens.

Comment: This looks like hardware problems, blinking keyboard lights is usually an extremely bad sign. Research in the documentation of your laptop for possible causes of this symptom. Maybe it's bad RAM or something like that, in this case you could boot into Memtest from the GRUB menu and let it check that.

Comment: When it freezes you could also try whether the kernel still reacts to the magic SysRq commands (I doubt it, but you can try). Therefore hold `Alt`+`SysRq` (that's usually on the same key as `PrintScr`, maybe you have to also hold `Fn`) and additionally slowly type `R`, `E`, `I`, `S`, `U`, `B`. Wait a few seconds after each keystroke and don't forget to keep holding down the `Alt`+`SysRq`. More info about the magic SysRq commands on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: So I suppose there is no point in reinstalling Ubuntu or testing with Windows?

Comment: Also memtest didn't find anything after 4 hours

Comment: I don't know. Of course you could try reinstalling Ubuntu or installing another OS, but I believe flashing keyboard LEDs are a sign for broken hardware, probably an on-board component. I first thought it could be the memory, but maybe it's also a thermal problem, heat making anything not work right. That would also explain why there's no obvious cause. But I can't guarantee I'm right, of course. Did you already research the notebook/mainboard service documentation whether they describe the blinking code you see?

Comment: I checked the manual - nothing about blinking lights. It might actually be a thermal problem. I remember years ago my laptop started to shutdown suddenly by itself. Cleaning the vents with a vacuum cleaner solved the problem back then. I'm gonna try that - or even have it cleaned in a repair center maybe.

Comment: So I have replaced the SDD (installed a few months ago) with the old HDD and it doesn't seem to be happening anymore. Not sure if I should try reinstalling the OS on the SSD first, or return it straight away?

Comment: I still  *think* it's probably a hardware problem (which would mean it's the SSD's fault), but that does not necessarily have to be true. If I was you, I'd rather just test it again with a fresh install than throwing the SSD right away, it was expensive enough, I guess.

Comment: I can have it replaced under warranty at the store by law (God bless Australia hehe) and it's too much trouble to reinstall. But I don't want to return a healthy SSD :/